# Running tasks sequentially in Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-contrib-copy

I was under the impression that in grunt.registerTask(taskName, taskList) the taskList would run sequentially (i.e. one completes before moving onto the next). I guess that is not the case?

Given this task:

```
grunt.registerTask('local-debug', [
    'clean',
    'concat:local',
    'ngconstant:common',
    'targethtml:local',
    'copy:debug'
]);
```

How can I make sure that concat/ngconstant/targethtml are complete before running copy? I'm having issues because the ngconstant is running before the concat has finished.

Edit: Details that tasks are not running sequentially.

'concat:local' creates a aggregate.json file used by 'ngconstant:common'. If I delete the existing aggregate.json file, the ngconstant:common task errors because the aggregate.json file is missing (but the file does get created, just after ngconstant runs). Also, if I don't delete the file, and just make a change like changing the version number in a source file that concat uses, the file created by ngconstant does not pick up the change because it does not wait until the new aggregate.json is created by concat.

Edit 2: task code

```
concat: {
        options: {
            banner: '{"appConfig": {',
            footer: "}}",
            separator: ','
        },
        local: {
            src: ["app/config/common-config.json", "app/config/local.json"],
            dest: "app/config/aggregate-config.json"
        }
    },
ngconstant: {
        options: {
            space: '  ',
            wrap: '(function(){\n\n"use strict";\n\n {%= __ngModule %}\n\n}());',
            name: 'CoreConfig',
            dest: 'app/scripts/config.js'
        },
        common: {
            constants: grunt.file.readJSON('app/config/aggregate-config.json')
        }
}
```

Comment: Grunt runs the task list sequentially, so your problem is probably elsewhere. What were the symptoms that made you think it did not?

Comment: Okay, that is what I thought, so I'll triple check all the tasks. I did add details to the question.

Comment: from your details it seems you are watching your files and the issue arises during watching, not calling `local-debug` directly. Please post the full config of your `watch` task then.

Comment: I happens when I manually call the `local-debug` task though, outside of any watch running.

Comment: um. Could you post your concat:local config then?

Comment: yup, I added the concat and ngconstant. Thank you for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, got it.

Grunt works by following the below steps:

1. its whole Gruntfile is read and the config is **evaluated**
2. then it builds the list of tasks to run
3. then it goes through the list, running tasks in sequence

So what happens is that your during 1., your file `aggregate-config.json` is read and sets `config.ngconstant.common.constants` to its **current** value (the result from your PREVIOUS run).
Then 3. happens, and a new `aggregate-config.json` is generated, but not used (config is NOT re-read between tasks).

But if you pass a **string** to `ngconstant.constants`, it is interpreted as a file name and read **when the task is run** (step 3), getting you the result you want:

```
ngconstant: {
  common: {
    constants: 'app/config/aggregate-config.json'
  }
}
```